# How to configure CMDB Health - cmdb_health_result for Audit Metric

Tags: dashboard, servicenow, cmdb

How to apply configuration for CMDB Compliance Dashboard. From my personal instance, In CMDB Health - > CMDB Compliance Scorecard, its showing calculated score is 57% {audit is showing 397/916 (43%)} How its calculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These scores are based on KPIs that are in the OOTB system, see [Enable and configure a CMDB Health Dashboard job](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/jakarta-servicenow-platform/page/product/configuration-management/task/t_EnableCMDBHealthDashboardJob.html) for the specific jobs.

These then feed in to the [CMDB Health](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/jakarta-servicenow-platform/page/product/configuration-management/concept/c_CMDBHealth.html) in this manner

> - **Completeness**: CIs are tested for required and recommended fields that are not populated.
> - **Correctness**: CIs are tested against pre-defined data integrity rules such as identification rules, orphan CI rules, and stale CI
>     rules.
> - **Compliance**: The CMDB data is audited for adherence to pre-defined certificates.
> - **Relationships**: The health of CI relationships is tested for indicators such as orphan and duplicate relationships. And for
>     compliance with suggested relationships, hosting and containment
>     rules.

Each of these are configurable within your instance using the [Guided Setup](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/jakarta-servicenow-platform/page/product/configuration-management/concept/c_CMDBHealthSetupandConfig.html)

To get to the specific spot:

- Navigate to **Guided Setup** > **ITOM Guided Setup** and click **Continue**.
- Under to **Configuration (CMDB)**, click **CMDB Health**.
- You can configure these there